# Very basic newcomer question - Do you gain anything back from running Smart Contracts on the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ether, gas

I have just finished reading a book on the Blockchain and Smart contracts ([https://www.amazon.com/Decentralized-Computing-Using-Technologies-Contracts/dp/1522521933](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1522521933))

I have a very basic newbie question arising from this, and I can't find the answer by Googling:

If I want to run a Smart Contract on the blockchain, I will need to purchase Ether with fiat money to use as gas.

If I use up all of the Ether I have purchased to to run my smart contract(s). I will have to go ahead and purchase more Ether to continue to run my smart contract(s).

Is there a way that one earns back Ether/gas by running smart contracts on the blockchain, or is it a never-ending process of purchasing Ether to continue running smart contracts on The Blockchain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can earn back ether by mining blocks on Ethereum by acting as a miner in the network. When you send a transaction to run a smart contract, it is actually run by the miner who creates the block and miner gets the gas that you sent with the transaction as reward for running your smart contract.

Comment: And if I don't earn Ether (by mining blocks) at the same rate as I spend Either (by running smart contracts)? No ROI?

Comment: Correct, if you are running the smart contract transactions only for the sake of it. But normally, we run a smart contract transaction only as part of a business, because we need to do it. For example, running a transaction on an insurance contract that sets Customer Signed = true. So the ethers spent is for a business purpose, whether you earn them from mining or buy from cash. Hope this clarifies.